# Insertar una terminal distinta de xterm en un Frame de una GUI construida en Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, terminal

He podido insertar una terminal xterm en un Frame de una GUI Tkinter con el siguiente código:

```
Frame2 = Frame(master)
Frame2.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
wid = Frame2.winfo_id()
os.system('xterm -into %d -hold -geometry 300x10 -sb &' % wid)
```

La pregunta es de qué forma puedo incluir por ejemplo la terminal konsole o la terminal gnome.

El siguiente código, por ejemplo, abre una terminal konsole, pero en una ventana aparte:

```
wid = Frame2.winfo_id()
os.system('konsole -geometry 300x10 %d &' % wid)
```

Comment: No puedes, al menos de la forma en que lo planteas. Con `xterm` no hay problema ya que trabaja directamente con el servidor `X` igual que `Tk` y además implementa la posibilidad de embeber la aplicación si le indicamos el `wid` de la ventana que hemos creado con `Tkinter`. `Konsole` esta montado sobre `QT` (bastante encima de `X`) y no implementa la funcionalidad mencionada en `xterm`.

Comment: @Patricio Moracho gracias. Yo dono los puntos igual así que si lo desea inclúyalo como respuesta para recibir la recompensa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con esto:

```
os.system('xterm -into %d -hold -geometry 300x10 -sb &' % wid)
```

Estas aprovechando que:

- `Tk` trabaja directamente con el servidor `X` del sistema, igual que `xterm`
- `xterm` por otro lado implementa la funcionalidad de poder embeber su interfaz en una ventana padre, el `WINDOW ID` que terminas enviándole es la referencia a la ventana creada con `Tk` mediante el parámetro `-into`

Para hacer esto en otras consolas, se deberían dar estas dos situaciones. Revisando la documentación de [`konsole`](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/konsole/command-line-options.html), que de por si trabaja sobre una "capa" superior (QT) no tiene documentada ninguna funcionalidad para embeber esta herramienta en otra aplicación. Por lo que lamentablemente no puedes usar `konsole` para integrarlo con la ventana `Tk`.